# JWT does not authorize roles, even when user has them

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core

I'm trying limit access to a controller.  Usings Roles, I've created a user with the roles however I'm getting an unauthorized exception.

```
[Authorize(Roles = ApiRoles.Consumer)]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StripePaymentsController : Controller
{
    //Omitted for simplicity
}
```

When I try to access any method on the controller I'm getting a 403, However, if I remove the Authorize attribute everything works fine.

I was under the impression that this would just work out of the box. e.g My User has the roles in the DB, when I attempt to access, I would just assume that it would use my user manager to check if the user has the correct role.

I can see my JWT has a claim for rol which I'm assuming means roles.

[image]

I'm wondering if I add my roles to the JWT manually maybe it will work?

**Edit:** Even if I add the roles in the Role Claim, it still fails authorization.

How does the authorization filter work under the hood? W
How can I authorize against roles using do I need to write custom mapping from the JWT?

Comment: 1) I had to add a `ClaimsIdentity` in a middleware, to pull claims off and the token and add them using `HttpContext.User.AddIdentity`. That makes them available, but the token signature is not validated until it hits an endpoint with `[Authorize]`. 2) I had to implement a `JwtBearerEvents` `OnTokenValidated` to assign the user to the `HttpContext.User` when the token is validated. I was upgrading from WebAPI to Core, so some things may be different. What do you have for JWT / context / claims processing so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check what role claim type is used by your `ClaimsIdentity` object (by checking the `RoleClaimType` property on the identity). By default, `ClaimTypes.Role` is used, meaning roles are checked against `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` claims. If you don't have such in your JWT, the `Roles` property won't work for you out of the box.

You can specify custom role type in `TokenValidationParameters` when configuring the JWT bearer options, by providing either `RoleClaimType` or `RoleClaimTypeRetriever` property.

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    RoleClaimType = "rol"
};
```

The above code changes role claim type to "rol", so the `rol` claims in your JWT will start acting as role claims.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out when I get back to that project tonight, Do you know how multiple claims are validated, Do I use a comma separated list or should I duplicate the role claim?

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1#adding-role-checks) out. *Each* `Authorize` attribute will be translated into *an* authorization requirement, depends on how you apply attribute or attributes, you can do AND and OR relationship separately. `Roles` requires multiple singular role claims in JWT, but if you have them combined in an array, you could always add your own [requirement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy) to a policy.

Comment: Thanks it all seems to checkout